# what is causing timeout errors in ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache

around 10 - 15% of my ajax calls fail due to the following error:

```
POST http://86.141.xxx.xx/page.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I don't know if this is an issue with the server (apache 2.9.4) or with my router. I never get these errors when testing in localhost. Is there any way to prevent/reduce theses errors. The ajax calls I make using jquery. something like the example below. Any advice much appreciated. Thanks

```
$.get('/check_session.php',function(data){
  if(data == "lo"){
    //do something
  }else{
    //do something else
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks like a connection issue. Is it just AJAX requests you've having issue with?

Comment: When you enter the address directly in your browser, does it take a long time to load?

Comment: @rmorrin mostly.Sometimes the page fails to load,  and shows 'webpage not available'. But then automatically reloads. Also sometimes it fails to load resources. But mostly Its the ajax calls

Comment: This is definitely connection/server issue.

Comment: @blex. Longer than most websites, yes, considering I am the only one on the server

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `timeout` option of the jquery ajax as following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/check_session.php',
  method: 'GET',
  timeout: 50000, //miliseconds
  success: function(){},
  error: function(){}
})
```

For more you can check [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it is due to the server host blocking rapid successive AJAX calls from the same IP address to secure the server against DDOS attacks.